# How to remove HTML tags from response JSON in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, eloquent

I am working on the Laravel rest api project project and came across a problem. I would like my function on my ApiController.php to bring me json object and remove html tags,. so i tried this method, How to remove html tags form response json laravel

```
class ApiControllerextends Controller
{
    //
    public function get(){
        $post =  Post::select('post_title','post_content','category_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->with('category')
            ->get();
            $categories=Category::all();
        return response()->json($post, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

The result that i get

```
Api Result
    [
        {
            "post_title": "post title 1",
            "post_content": "<p>content</p> my content &quot is  :<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>- content</p>",
            "category_id": "1",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "category1",
            }
        },
    ]
```

so how to get the result i want to show

```
Api Result
        [
            {
                "post_title": "post title 1",
                "post_content": "content my content is content",
                "category_id": "1",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "category1",
                }
            },
        ]
```

Comment: You don't appear to have made any real attempt to solve this problem. Making up methods (`response()->strip_tags()`???) is not a good faith effort to do your own work.

Comment: @miken32 I spent more than five days trying to find a solution because I am going through the laravel framwork, your help will be welcome

Comment: check my improved answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
public function get(){
        $post =  Post::select('post_title','post_content','category_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->with('category')
            ->get();
            $categories=Category::all();
        foreach ($post as $item){
              $post->post_content=strip_tags($post->post_content);

         }
        return response()->json($post, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr @Evol Rof ,i got this error code when i tried this method Exception: Property [post_content] does not exist on this collection instance. in file C:\laravelproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php on line 837

Comment: Mr @Evol Rof it worked perfectly thank you very much i appreciate your help you're the best,i just added html_entity_decode
foreach ($post as $item){
                $item->post_content=strip_tags(html_entity_decode($item->post_content));
            }